# Single Pixel Color Correction

Tags: android, graphics, colors, bitmap

I've created an android application that produces an image as output. This image has pixel errors that are unavoidable. Images are held in an integer array with a size of the image's length*width. The pixels are in ARGB8888 color configuration. I've been searching for a method to both find and approximate what the correct value of the pixel should be based off the surrounding pixels. Here is an example output that needs to be color corrected.

[image: output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Median filter is your best friend in this situation. This is called salt-and-pepper noise.

Comment: The median filter works great. The image is a little blurrier then I would like but, the blur is much better then the noise. Thanks

Comment: I've rewritten my algorithm to only preform the filter on problem pixels this has reduced the blur while still removing the noise. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't look (or sound) like what is normally meant by "color correction". Look for a [despeckle](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Reducing_CCD_Noise/) algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

[Gaussian filter](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/gsmooth.htm) might work, or [Crimmins](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/crimmins.htm) Speckle Removal.  You'll probably want to understand how [Kernel Filters](http://www.cyanogen.com/help/maximdl/Kernel_Filter.htm) work.